# Generate a dynamic ID for every instance of radio button using formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am using **angular-formly** to generate radio groups. Everything works well except at a point where these radio buttons are being generated dynamically depending on some condition.

**The Problem**

Every instance of radio buttons gets the same dynamic ID generated by following formly template. As a result when I click on any radio button on the page, the first one gets selected as the ID attribute is always same.

```
 function addRadioType(formlyConfigProvider) {
   formlyConfigProvider.setType({
     name: 'radio',
     template: '<div class="radio-group vk">'
                   +'<div ng-repeat="(key, option) in to.options" class="radio">'
       +'<input type="radio"  id="{{id + \'_\'+ $index}}" tabindex="0" ng-value="option[to.valueProp || \'value\']" '
       +' ng-model="model[options.key]">'
        +'<label for="{{id + \'_\'+ $index}}">'
        +' {{option[to.labelProp || \'name\']}}'
      +' </label>'
     +'</div>'
   +'</div>'
    ,
     wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
     defaultOptions: {
       noFormControl: false
     },
     apiCheck: check => ({
       templateOptions: {
         options: check.arrayOf(check.object),
         labelProp: check.string.optional,
         valueProp: check.string.optional
       }
     })
   });
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that $index stays the same throughout the ng-repeat loop?

Comment: No there isn't any ng-repeat but there is a function which displays the radio button depending on value selected in a select box

Comment: Basically I want different Id on each function call

Comment: In that case, add the id to your 'to.options' object ('check.object' I presume), and instead of {{id + \'_\'+ $index}}, it would be something like: {{id + \'_\'+ option.id}} depending on your 'check.object' data structure.

Comment: But this will require me to pass an id for other radio groups as well which are not part of this current problem set. The problem with that is it's a huge code base and I may not be able to manually edit every other radio group effectively. Is there any other way I can manage to generate a dynamic id where either I could simply modify the formly template or somehow manipulate the function which returns these particular radio groups